# MathJax not rendering on html page

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I added MathJax to the header of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
```

I add Latex to body:

```
<body>
    \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} V\left(f\left(\vec{x}_{i}\right), y_{i}\right)+\gamma\|f\|_{\mathcal{H}}^{2}
</body>
```

I refresh page, and only the raw latex appears.

Is there something else needed to render the latex as math? The [documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/index.html) says configurations are default and MathJax should simply search the page for latex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with the result but maybe you need to put it inside `\[...\]`

```html
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

<p>
\[
    \frac{1}{n}
    \sum_{i=1}^{n}
    V\left(f\left(\vec{x}_{i}\right), y_{i}\right)+\gamma\|f\|_{\mathcal{H}}^{2}
\]
```